# Morelinq ExceptBy using several specific element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, .net-3.5, morelinq

There are 2 xml files

First xml file contains:

```
<Prices>
    <Price>
        <SalesOrg>700</SalesOrg>
        <AreaOfPricing>D20</AreaOfPricing>
        <ProductId>20228090</ProductId>
        <EffectiveDate>2015-05-11T00:00:00+7</EffectiveDate>
        <DistributorPriceFibrate>200</DistributorPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceFibrate>20</CustomerPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceInDozen>30</CustomerPriceInDozen>
        <CustomerPriceinPC>80.00</CustomerPriceinPC>
        <CompanyID>001</CompanyID>
        <ValidTo>2999-12-31T00:00:00+7</ValidTo>
        <UOM>CS</UOM>
        <Currency>IDR</Currency>
    </Price>
<Price>
        <SalesOrg>700</SalesOrg>
        <AreaOfPricing>D20</AreaOfPricing>
        <ProductId>20228090</ProductId>
        <EffectiveDate>2015-05-11T00:00:00+7</EffectiveDate>
        <DistributorPriceFibrate>200</DistributorPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceFibrate>20</CustomerPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceInDozen>30</CustomerPriceInDozen>
        <CustomerPriceinPC>80.00</CustomerPriceinPC>
        <CompanyID>001</CompanyID>
        <ValidTo>2999-12-31T00:00:00+7</ValidTo>
        <UOM>CS</UOM>
        <Currency>IDR</Currency>
    </Price>
<Price>
        <SalesOrg>700</SalesOrg>
        <AreaOfPricing>D20</AreaOfPricing>
        <ProductId>20228090</ProductId>
        <EffectiveDate>2015-05-11T00:00:00+7</EffectiveDate>
        <DistributorPriceFibrate>180</DistributorPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceFibrate>20</CustomerPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceInDozen>30</CustomerPriceInDozen>
        <CustomerPriceinPC>80.00</CustomerPriceinPC>
        <CompanyID>001</CompanyID>
        <ValidTo>2999-12-31T00:00:00+7</ValidTo>
        <UOM>CS</UOM>
        <Currency>IDR</Currency>
    </Price>
</Prices>
```

and the second xml file:

```
<Prices>
    <Price>
        <SalesOrg>700</SalesOrg>
        <AreaOfPricing>D20</AreaOfPricing>
        <ProductId>20228090</ProductId>
        <EffectiveDate>2015-05-11T00:00:00+7</EffectiveDate>
        <DistributorPriceFibrate>200</DistributorPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceFibrate>20</CustomerPriceFibrate>
        <CustomerPriceInDozen>30</CustomerPriceInDozen>
        <CustomerPriceinPC>80.00</CustomerPriceinPC>
        <CompanyID>001</CompanyID>
        <ValidTo>2999-12-31T00:00:00+7</ValidTo>
        <UOM>CS</UOM>
        <Currency>IDR</Currency>
    </Price>
</Prices>
```

What I want is, using morelinq features `ExceptBy()`, or using custom class extend IEqualityComparer on Except() features in Linq to return something like this (between 1st xml file and the 2nd xml file, even when the third tag price on 1st xml file have different `DistributorPriceFibrate` value):

```
<Prices/>
```

Since `Except()` compares all values on element 'Price' node, I just want compare only specific element at `<ProductId>` and `<EffectiveDate>` only.

If they are the same, then go empty tag `<Prices/>`. If not same value on those elements, return the price tag from 1st xml file which not have same value `ProductID` and `EffectiveDate` from 2nd xml file.

What I've done I distinct the 1st xml file:

```
var distinctItemsonxmldoc1 =
                xmldoc1
                .Descendants("Price")
                .DistinctBy(element => new
                {
                    ProductId = (string)element.Element("ProductId"),
                    EffectiveDate = (string)element.Element("EffectiveDate")
                });
var afterdistinctxmldoc1 = new XElement("Prices");
            foreach (var a in distinctItemsonxmldoc1 )
            {
                afterdistinctxmldoc1.Add(a);
            }
```

and when using except to compare between 2 files:

```
var afterexcept = afterdistinctxmldoc1.Descendants("Price").Cast<XNode>().Except(xmldoc2.Descendants("Price").Cast<XNode>(), new XNodeEqualityComparer());
```

but it compare all element value on price node.
how using ExceptBy() in spesific element?
or custom IComparer maybe?

Thanks before.

EDIT
already solved. [see the answer by @dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30156960/4879637).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm I understand your question: given two XML documents, you want to enumerate through instances of each `Price` element in the first document with *distinct* values values for the child elements `ProductId` and `EffectiveDate`, skipping all those whose `ProductId` and `EffectiveDate` match a `Price` element in the second document, using [`MoreLinq`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/).

In that case, you can do:

```
        var diff = xmldoc1.Descendants("Price").ExceptBy(xmldoc2.Descendants("Price"),
            e => new { ProductId = e.Elements("ProductId").Select(p => p.Value).FirstOrDefault(), EffectiveDate = e.Elements("EffectiveDate").Select(p => p.Value).FirstOrDefault() });
```

Comment: yes, i need to get `<price>` node from first xml file when EffectiveDate is different or has new date. the second xml file is reference.

Comment: i tried your snippet code, and it seems working, maybe you just solved my problem. thanks!